# How to input 'Registered Trademark' Glyph in Inkscape?

Tags: text, inkscape, tools, glyphs

I went to: <kbd>Text → Glyphs →</kbd>  and found the symbol. However, I can't get it from the window box to the artboard.

I've searched Google & YouTube, but cannot find the answer. How do I type in the Registered ‎® symbol in Inkscape?

Comment: If you are lazy (like I am) google the symbol as unicode, cut and paste.

Comment: Most programs will let you type Option (Mac)/ Alt (PC) and the letter R to get the Registered symbol. Haven't used Inkscape yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the *Glyphs* panel (*Text → Glyphs*). Select a text element. Click on the glyph you want, and click the *Append* button in the bottom-right.

[image: GIF screencast of the same]

If you want it in your clipboard, double-click the glyph to add it to the text-field in the bottom left of the panel—you can copy it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to insert the registered symbol using Unicode in Inkscape:

1. Start a text area.
2. Press `Ctrl+U`
3. Type `00AE` and hit enter. Keep your eye on the bottom status bar, to preview the symbol being inserted.

Answer (score 0):

If using Linux like Ubuntu, You may use (GNOME) Tweaks to set the option.

Check out this [Compose Key with Gnome Tweaks](https://askubuntu.com/a/1028964/281645)

And view the compose file with

```
gedit /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose
```